# C# writing to app.config file

Tags: c#, configuration

I understand how to get a handle and write to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration> 
  <appSettings>  
    <add key="Param1" value="" />  
    <add key="Param2" value="" />  
    <add key="Param3" value="" />  
  </appSettings>  
</configuration>
```

But what about when it's structured like this?

```
<configuration>
    <userSettings>
        <MyEXEName.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="some_setting" serializeAs="String>
                <value>some value</value>
            </setting>
        </MyEXEName.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You can try using ConfigurationManager.GetSection though I'm not sure such structure can be accessed with it. I've only used Key/Value structure, same as appSettings and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Net Framework and Visual Studio are kind enough to generate a static `Properties` class on your application namespace. You can access and set the user settings through this class. Take into account that the settings values are saved in the user's roaming profile, so even though the config file in your app's folder has some settings, the user settings are saved somewhere in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData`.

Following the provided info, you would access the property like:

```
MyEXEName.Properties.Settings.some_setting = "new value";
```

Comment: I have these in the Settings, you're correct. When the code is deployed via MSI, I want to change the app.config. I have a custom installer class, that's taking user entered values from custom text entry screens of the installer. When the program runs, you're saying the MyEXE.app.config values aren't used?

Comment: Settings can belong to the Application scope or the User scope. Application scoped settings are read-only at execution time (through Properties.Settings). User scoped settings are read/write at execution time and are saved in User.config inside the AppData folder. Look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: Getting a handle to the config file was my big problem, and this line of code made everything finally work.  Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

Answer (score 1):

Then you want [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zszyc6e.aspx).

Here's an example (lifted from MSDN):

```
public class MyUserSettings : ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    [UserScopedSetting()]
    [DefaultSettingValue("white")]
    public Color BackgroundColor
    {
        get
        {
            return ((Color)this["BackgroundColor"]);
        }
        set
        {
            this["BackgroundColor"] = (Color)value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
MyUserSettings mus;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mus = new MyUserSettings();
    mus.BackgroundColor = Color.AliceBlue;
    this.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("BackColor", mus, "BackgroundColor"));
}

void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    mus.Save();
}
```

I recommend reading the whole section on MSDN, though, as it provides lots of useful information.

Answer (score 0):

```
string someSetting = Settings.Default.some_setting;
```

This file is auto generated by the VS you can open it in project->properties->Settings.settings.
When you execute the application note that this setting is saved in %APPDATA% that is the application user folder (you can search *.config because the folder inside %APPDATA% has a random name).